# Require multiple files dynamically using webpack bundle loader

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have been trying to load multiple files in a single require using bundle-loader plugin of webpack. Below is how require a single file.

```
var waitForChunk = require("bundle-loader!./file.js");

// To wait until the chunk is available (and get the exports)
//  you need to async wait for it.
waitForChunk(function(file) {
    // use file like is was required with
    // var file = require("./file.js");
});
// wraps the require in a require.ensure block
```

But couldn't figure out how this can be achieved , any idea?

Answer (score 1):

As far I see in the docs and other examples I don't think using loaders in `require` supports multiple files; instead could load a single file/bundle.

Although webpack has this feature of using [loaders in `require`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#loaders-in-require) for loading dynamic dependencies, webpack docs discourages its use.

> Avoid using this, if at all possible, if you intend your scripts to be
>   environment agnostic (node.js and browser). Use the configuration
>   convention for specifying loaders ([see it
>   here](http://webpack.github.io/docs/using-loaders.html#configuration)).

The [`bundle-loader`](https://github.com/webpack/bundle-loader) wraps a file in a `require.ensure` block. So why don't we go with the original [`require.ensure`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html#commonjs-require-ensure) way? You can load multiple dynamic dependencies as follows:

**`require.ensure(dependencies, callback)`;**

> The `require.ensure` method ensures that every dependency in
>   dependencies can be synchronously required when calling the callback.
>   callback is called with the require function as parameter.

See the below examples. The modules `require`d inside `require.ensure` is not loaded until you call the `loadAsyncDeps` function.

**example 1:**

```
function loadAsyncDeps(moduleName, cb)
    // `module-a` and `module-b` can now be split into different files,
    // and the callback function will not run until they have loaded.
    require.ensure(['./module-a', './module-b'], function(require) {
        var modules = {
            a: require('./module-a'),
            b: require('./module-b'),
            // ...
        };

        cb(modules[moduleName]); // callback fn which returns required module
    });
}
```

**example 2:**

```
function loadAsyncDeps(moduleName, cb)
    require.ensure([], function() {  //empty first param
        var modules = {
            a: require('./module-a'),
            b: require('./module-b'),
            // ...
        };

        cb(modules[moduleName]); // callback fn which returns required module
    }, 'my-lazy-modules');
}
```

Here `require.ensure` defines a split point. Everything goes into a single chunk named `my-lazy-modules`.

---

#### UPDATE:

**How to create separate chunk for each of these files? ie, `module-a` and `module-b` should go to two different chunks with proper name.**

Create separate functions for loading `module-a` and `module-b`

Here `module-a-1` and `module-a-1` are dependencies of `module-a`

```
require.ensure(['./module-a', './module-a-1', './module-a-2'], function(require) {
    var a = require('./module-a');
}, 'lazy-module-a');
```

`module-b-1` and `module-b-2` are dependencies of `module-b`
module

```
require.ensure(['./module-b', './module-b-1', './module-b-2'], function(require) {
    var b = require('./module-b');
}, 'lazy-module-b');
```

As quoted above, the callback function is not invoked until all modules in the dependency array is loaded (and safe for a synchronous `require`).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried the first example and it  is automatically creating chunks, but the name is different, I need to have the exact same name, is there any way I can achieve this.

Comment: What do you mean "the name is different"? What name are you referring to? (Did you mean the chunks' name? then go with the second approach, all your lazy modules will be loaded in one chunk)

Comment: The name of the chunks getting created is something like 'module-2-f00601910a6235399a4f', it is not creating the chunks with exact name

Comment: do you want to merge that to an existing chunk or do you want all your dynamic modules in one single chunk?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, Actually I am trying to migrate one big app with requirejs to webpack.. these modules are already defined and very large files.. so I want to create separate chunk for each of these files, ie, module-a and module-b should go to two different chunks with proper name. Thanks

Comment: is something like this will work    require.ensure(['./module-a', './module-b'], function(require) {
       
    },'module-a','module-b');

Comment: See the update in my answer, let me know if that helps you.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same when `'./module-a'`, `'./module-b'` are dynamic? I'm trying to see if I can abstract out `require.ensure` calls (it's not just require.ensure that I'm abstracting, there is a bunch of common logic that happens afterwards).